# java robot turning circle understeering

Tags: java

I am building a robot in java and I am implementing a turning system which calculates the angle between two coordinates (x1, y1), (x2, y2), however the robot is currently underturning i.e. if i told it to turn 90 degress it would only turn 40 so I need to input more steering. The robot can turn left or right dependning on whether the turn required is greater than 180. Below the code works but only if the starting heading is at 0 degrees so i need the code to take into consideration the current position.

```
        double xDiff = x2 - x1;
        double yDiff = y2 - y1;
        double angle =  Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff));

        double currentAngle = 0; //is changed after first run 

        angle = (angle + 360) % 360; 

        angle = angle - currentAngle;
```

makes the angle between -180 and 180

```
     if (angle > 180)  
         angle -= 360;

        if(angle < 0 )
        {
            angle = angle - 45;

        }
        else if(angle > 0)
        {
            angle = angle + 45;

        }
```

Comment: This line sounds weird: `double yDiff = x2 - y1`. Is `double yDiff = y2 - y1` not better ?

Comment: @Benoit yeah sorry I had different variables names there on the actual program and this was a mistake I input on stack, I'll edit this thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use angles for this. (Don't use angles for anything, if you can possibly avoid it.) If the dot product between this frame's `[xDiff,yDiff]` and the current heading vector is negative, the angle is greater than 180 degrees. (Also, the perp dot product indicates whether you need to turn left or right.)